# BackPress returns to blank activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have implemented barcode scanner in my app. I have an activity that contains multiple fragment. On one fragment I have a scan barcode button and on clicking that button it jumps to scan activity to scan code and returns to fragment with the code.

But the problem is this when I get a got then it opens a dialog on previous fragment with code and when I click on toolbar's back press from that current fragment then it shows white blank activity.

```
 @Override
public void handleResult(me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.Result result) {


    String resultCode = result.getContents();

    Log.e("TAG", "handleResult: " + resultCode);
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
    modelProductArticleCodeList = new ArrayList<>();
    modelProductArticleCodeList = databaseHelper.getProductByArtCode(resultCode);


    if (modelProductArticleCodeList.size() == 0) {

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(1000);


        singleUnrecognisedCheck = new ArrayList<>();

        singleUnrecognisedCheck = databaseHelper.getUnrecognisedByCode(resultCode);

        if (singleUnrecognisedCheck.size() == 0) {

            Intent in = new Intent(this, ContainAllFragmentsActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("unrecognised_alert", true);
            in.putExtra("unrecognised_code", resultCode);
            in.putExtra("jump", "1");
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(in);
            finishAffinity();
            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
            //  Toast.makeText(this, "not matched code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, ContainAllFragmentsActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("jump", "3");
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(in);
            finishAffinity();
            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.unrecognised_code_has_been_added, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    } else {

       }

        Intent in = new Intent(this, ContainAllFragmentsActivity.class);

        in.putExtra("product_art", resultCode);
        in.putExtra("source_type", "art");
        in.putExtra("jump", "2");
        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(in);
        finishAffinity();
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);

    }
}
```

And based on key params and value in Intent activity switches to particular fragment.

```
if (switchTonext.equals("1")) {
            Fragment fragment = new SearchProductFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); // this is basically context of the class
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putBoolean("unrecognised_alert", unrecognised_alert);
            bundle.putString("unrecognised_code", getIntent().getStringExtra("unrecognised_code"));

            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

To resolve this problem I made some changes in **onBackPressed** in activity and hard coded that if fragment is instance of that current fragment that upon click back button change to previous one.

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
    if (!(f instanceof SearchShopFragment)) {
        if (f instanceof SearchProductFragment) {
            changeFragments(new SearchShopFragment());
        }
        else if(f instanceof ProductDetailFragment){
            changeFragments(new SearchProductFragment());
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.exit_msg);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                moveTaskToBack(true);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                finish();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no
                , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

This achieves removing blank activity but now all my data in fragment vanishes when I press back button. I don't have data in fragment when I press back button.

Please help!! How can I resolve these two problems.

Comment: Instead of the blank activity, which page do you want to go from the back button?

Comment: Add  `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>` to your app theme.

Comment: To the last visited fragment i.e. SearchShop @MichaelLam

Comment: Try to use popbacktostack instead of passing new fragment object in "changeFragment" function

Comment: Have you checked if the blank activity is the `Scan Activity`? 
Like @Parul said, avoid doing manual fragment transaction in `onBackPressed` and let `backStack` handle it

Comment: How can I add popbacktostack in activity on back press @Parul

Answer (score 1):

Try this in onBackPressed:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frame);

 if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1){
         fm.popBackStack();
    } else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to solve this problem,
1) put the logic of Scan Code in the same Fragment where you take the action after clicking the Scan button (Avoid Scan Activity).. (When Button is clicked, make invisiable it and visible the UI for scan code).. #NO_need_to_Create_Scan_Code_Activity_seperatetly..

2) On getting the result of Scan, or on pressing the back in your ScanActivity, set the fragment tag in putExtra("FRAGMENT_TO_BE_LOAD", "") before destroying it and call your ContainAllFragmentsActivity, and loads the same fragment which is set in tag. For this use getIntent().getExtra()...

Comment: Thanks, but not able to understand your 2nd solution.

Comment: 2nd solution is considering you created activity say 'ActivityScanCode' for scanning.
On getting the scan result or on pressing the back you have to call ContainAllFragmentsActivity which loads the same Fragment from where you gone to ActivityScanCode, 
So in the ActivityScanCode before leaving it, set fragment_page and scanCodeResult flags in intent as a putExtra("Fragement_to_be_load", Fragment_Something.class);  and putExtra("scanCodeResult", resScanCode) 
and call ContainAllFragmentsActivity, and after it handle these flags in handleIntentData() and load the Fragment in the intent data.